# Не отрабатывает внешняя команда если выполнять через exec()

Tags: php, openserver, exec

Windows 10/OpenServer 5.2.2/PHP 7.2
Пытаюсь в файле выполнить exec() с java командой

```
<?php exec("java -jar closure-compiler/closure-compiler.jar --js C:/path_to_file/file.js --js_output_file C:/path_to_file/file.min.js"); ?>
```

При  вызове данного файла - ничего не происходит. Если запустить эту же команду в консоли - генерирует файл file.min.js

Путь к исполняемому файлу java прописан в PATH Windows

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Где код вызова?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Поправил. Файл вызываю через браузер.

Comment: Подозреваю, что сервер запущен под другим пользователем и у него чего-то не хватает

Comment: @AlexeyTen Сервер запущен от имени администратора

Comment: И PATH у него прописан? И текущий рабочий каталог такой же? Попробуйте указать полный путь к closure-compiler

Comment: @AlexeyTen PATH чего должен быть прописан? OpenServer? Зачем?
Правда Windows и OpenServer находятся на разных дисках...
Полный путь к файлу closure-compiler.jar прописал - ничего не изменилось

Comment: Путь до java. И посмотрите уже наконец что возвращает exec. Ещё у него дополнительные параметры есть

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я же в шапке написал, что путь к java прописан в PATH. Второй параметр возвращает пустой массив, третий - '1'.

Comment: А вы в курсе, что PATH у каждого пользователя свой? И 1 значит произошла ошибка https://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/events/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/

Comment: И вообще выведите phpinfo и посмотрите что там за пользователь и какие пути есть

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вывел phpinfo, как оказалось, php не видел PATH самого windows, у него были свои локальные. В настройках Open Server указал "Свой PATH + Win PATH, ребут сервера и полетело. Спасибо большое за помощь! Развернутый ответ с описанием сделаю ответом под постом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в PATH, которых не видел php.

Функция exec() отдавала вторым параметром пустой массив; третьим - '1'(что говорит об ошибке).

```
<?php 
exec("java -jar closure-compiler/closure-compiler.jar --js C:/path_to_file/file.js --js_output_file C:/path_to_file/file.min.js", $output, $status);

print_r($output); // Array()
print_r($status); // 1

 ?>
```

Решение проблемы:

- В OpenServer Настройки->Сервер
- Поле : Настройка использования переменной Path
- Установить : "Свой PATH + Win PATH"
  [image: Установить : "Свой PATH + Win PATH"]
- Перезагрузка OpenServer 
  При всем этом при установке Java на Windows, PATH автоматически будет сгенерирован 
  [image: path Java in windows]